# Unable to connect when LDAP Channel Binding is enabled

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, netldap

Trying to connect to AD by enforcing the LDAP Channel Binding https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV190023

Ending up with the below error

```
=> #<Net::LDAP::PDU:0x0000000013568ea8
  @app_tag=1,
  @ldap_controls=[],
  @ldap_result=
      {:resultCode=>49,
       :matchedDN=>"",
       :errorMessage=>"80090346: LdapErr: DSID-0C09056D, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 80090346, v2580\u0000"},
  @message_id=1>
```

Does anyone know is there a way how to connect by enabling the channel binding?